# Problemas con Inversión de cadenas en C

Tags: c

tengo un problema con La inversión de cadenas en C. En este programa se pide al usuario ingresar la cantidad de palabras que se desea invertir. Cuando el programa corre solo una vez, sin el bucle principal, el programa funciona perfectamente (para solo un caso),pero si uso el bucle principal, el programa falla . En algunos casos de prueba se almacena datos basura en la palabra invertida o en otros casos la palabra invertida almacena parte de la cadena  de la palabra invertida anterior. Si me pueden ayudar a resolver esta duda, se los agradecería mucho. Acá está el código:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void)
{
    int indice;
    unsigned short casos, i, longitud, j;
    char palabra[41];
    char palabraInvertida[41];
    scanf("%hu", &casos);
    i = 1;

    // --------------------------------------Proceso------------------------------------
    // BUCLE PRINCIPAL. 
    while (i <= casos){

        // Entrada.
        scanf("%s",palabra);

        longitud = strlen(palabra);
        // 'indice' representa el indice del último caracter de la cadena 'palabra'. 
        indice = longitud - 1;

        /*
         * Proceso para invertir la palabra original. Se almacenará en 'palabraInvertida' los caracteres
         * de 'palabra', pero a partir desde el último caracter.
         */
        for (j = 0 ; j < longitud ; j++){

            palabraInvertida[j] = palabra[indice];
            indice --;
        }
        if (isupper(palabra[0])){
            palabraInvertida[0] = toupper(palabraInvertida[0]);
            palabraInvertida[longitud - 1] = tolower(palabraInvertida[longitud - 1]);
        }

        printf("%s\n",palabraInvertida);
        i ++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pues parece que [funciona](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JXcdyok8ckC116Sd) bien

Answer (score 2):

Nunca le añades el `\0` terminador a `palabraInvertida`, así que las funciones `str` y `print` no saben donde termina el string.

Un string es básicamente una cadena de carácteres que termina en `\0` (valor 0 en ASCII). Mientras uses funciones de string es transparente, pero cuando trabajas directamente con `char` lo tienes que tener en cuenta.

```
Original :  S J u a n 7 6 \0 X 1 z n p € @

Invertida : 7 6 n a u J S 3 2 8 # d m n p
```

Cuando hagas printf, en el primer caso te imprimirá hasta el `\0`, en el segundo también, pero el `\0` estará "en algún sitio" (y si no está en el array, tienes "undefined behavior").

La primera vez te funciona porque es probable que todo el array esté inicializado a 0, pero en siguientes iteraciones, al poner palabras más cortas te encuentras que ves las letras que dejaste en iteraciones anteriores.

```
Iteración 1: SJuan76

Original :  S J u a n 7 6 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0
Invertida : 7 6 n a u J S \0 \0 \0 \0 \0

Iteración 2: SJu

Original :  S J u \0 7 6 \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 --> El \0 lo pone scanf
Invertida : u J S a u J S \0 \0 \0 \0 \0 --> Nadie pone \0
```

Solución: Añade el `\0` ("terminador de Strings") al segundo array donde toca.

```
palabraInvertida[longitud] = (char) 0;
```

Comment: En otro orden de cosas, cuanta más información (relevante) del problema des, más probable es que tengas respuesta y más rápidamente llegará. Si en vez de decir "pongo valores y me sale texto raro" hubieras puesto qué valores ponías y qué texto te sale, la gente habría tenido mucho más fácil reproducir este problema.